# RLP related question

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I am trying to translate solidity code in smartpy .

bytes memory rlpBytes;

rlpBytes = abi.encodePacked(rlpBytes, _link.encodeString());

rlpBytes = abi.encodePacked(
rlpBytes.length.addLength(false),
rlpBytes
);

here _link is a string data type.

I am using the below function of rlp for decoding
https://github.com/airgap-it/ibcf/blob/291964a41ebecc25961435e106086854390662c5/contracts/tezos/libs/utils.py#L179

I am using the function in this way ,
rlp_bytes = sp.local("rlp_bytes", sp.build_lambda(rlp.Encoder.encode_string)(link))

But i got stuck on the second line
rlpBytes = abi.encodePacked(
rlpBytes.length.addLength(false),
rlpBytes
);

Can someone help me out here on this line ?
I am having trouble translating this .

Answer (score 1):

Does the encoding need to be the same in both Tezos and EVM contracts? Or can you use the Tezos encoding instead (with `sp.pack` and `sp.unpack`)?

If the encoding needs to be the same:

**Solidity**:

```
function encode(bytes memory rlpBytes, string memory link) external pure returns(bytes memory) {
  // rlpBytes = 0x80
  // link = "TEST"
  // result = 0x8054455354
  return abi.encodePacked(rlpBytes, link);
}
```

**SmartPy**

```
import smartpy as sp

Utils = sp.io.import_script_from_url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Acurast/acurast-hyperdrive/main/contracts/tezos/libs/utils.py")

@sp.add_test("Tests")
def test():
 sc = sp.test_scenario()

 rlpBytes = sp.bytes("0x80") # can be any bytes
 encode_string_packed = sp.build_lambda(Utils.Bytes.of_string)
 sc.show(rlpBytes + encode_string_packed("TEST")) # 0x8054455354
```

About `rlpBytes = abi.encodePacked( rlpBytes.length.addLength(false), rlpBytes );`, it should be the same as doing `RLP.Encoder.with_length_prefix(rlpBytes)`. Need more context to give a precise answer.

Also, https://github.com/airgap-it/ibcf has been moved to https://github.com/Acurast/acurast-hyperdrive.

Comment: So I added , 
 sc.show(Utils.RLP.Encoder.with_length_prefix(rlpBytes)) on the above code , 
to achieve this code 
rlpBytes = abi.encodePacked( rlpBytes.length.addLength(false), rlpBytes );

but it says error while compiling, 
Error: New command outside of contract

Comment: `bytes memory _rlpBytes; ` <br/>
`_rlpBytes = abi.encodePacked(_rlpBytes, _link.encodeString()); `
`_rlpBytes = abi.encodePacked(
            _rlpBytes.length.addLength(false),_rlpBytes); `

     
       `_rlpBytes = abi
            .encodePacked(_rlpBytes.length.addLength(false), _rlpBytes)
            .encodeBytes(); `
This is the part of a code from a function of solidity that I am trying to translate using smartpy.

Comment: You need to build the lambda first: `with_length_prefix = sp.build_lambda(Utils.RLP.with_length_prefix)` and then just use `with_length_prefix(rlpBytes)`

Comment: can you help me out here too on decoding https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/5972/rlp-decoding-on-tezos

Comment: Hi can you see this post once 
https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/rlp-encoding-of-solidity

Comment: I have provided another example there.