# RLP decoding on tezos

Tags: smartpy, encoding

I have a code where a string "TEST" is encoded using RLP,
https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmNVpo55Ss43aZiyrkdbEWcmmQEAsR2qHLKsPcLbqie7yu&k=8d516a673d972f3204f0

How do we decode the obtained bytes back to normal string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
import smartpy as sp

Utils = sp.io.import_script_from_url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Acurast/acurast-hyperdrive/main/contracts/tezos/libs/utils.py")

@sp.add_test("Tests")
def test():
 sc = sp.test_scenario()
    
 link = "TEST"
 encode_string = sp.build_lambda(Utils.RLP.Encoder.encode_string)
 rlpEncodedString = encode_string(link)
    
 sc.show(rlpEncodedString)
    
 decode_string = sp.build_lambda(Utils.RLP.Decoder.decode_string)
 sc.show(decode_string(rlpEncodedString))
```

Comment: I have added with_length_prefix too while encoding, 

 with_length_prefix = sp.build_lambda(Utils.RLP.Encoder.with_length_prefix)
 rlp_bytes_with_prefix = with_length_prefix(rlpEncodedString)

while decoding this it is giving a strange value to me , Will we be able to decode the rlp bytes where the decoded add_length_prefix part becomes first element of list and string TEST is second element of the list. 
 https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmcQLEiUEoMiGypVdb2wGhVXCQiifKf4xvVQ6FPPMdFpBk&k=4ab6a6ad400ca9ea0e7f

Comment: The `with_length_prefix` is redundant. It is already done in `encode_string`. https://github.com/Acurast/acurast-hyperdrive/blob/e6e73b1ffa5ac539d135846183b839fdb2c8f802/contracts/tezos/libs/utils.py#L193