# rlp encoding of solidity

Tags: smartpy

there are two functions on solidity

```
function encodeString(string memory self)
        internal
        pure
        returns (bytes memory)
    {
        return encodeBytes(bytes(self));
    }
```

```
/**
     * @dev RLP encodes a byte string.
     * @param self The byte string to encode.
     * @return The RLP encoded string in bytes.
     */
    function encodeBytes(bytes memory self)
        internal
        pure
        returns (bytes memory)
    {
        bytes memory encoded;
        if (self.length == 1 && uint8(self[0]) <= 128) {
            encoded = self;
        } else {
            encoded = concat(encodeLength(self.length, 128), self);
        }
        return encoded;
    }
```

```
/**
     * @dev Encode the first byte, followed by the `len` in binary form if `length` is more than 55.
     * @param len The length of the string or the payload.
     * @param offset 128 if item is string, 192 if item is list.
     * @return RLP encoded bytes.
     */
    function encodeLength(uint256 len, uint256 offset)
        private
        pure
        returns (bytes memory)
    {
        bytes memory encoded;
        if (len < 56) {
            encoded = new bytes(1);
            encoded[0] = bytes32(len + offset)[31];
        } else {
            uint256 lenLen;
            uint256 i = 1;
            while (len / i != 0) {
                lenLen++;
                i *= 256;
            }

            encoded = new bytes(lenLen + 1);
            encoded[0] = bytes32(lenLen + offset + 55)[31];
            for (i = 1; i <= lenLen; i++) {
                encoded[i] = bytes32((len / (256**(lenLen - i))) % 256)[31];
            }
        }
        return encoded;
    }
```

It is being called this way
_rlpBytes = abi.encodePacked(_rlpBytes, _link.encodeString());

Is this already implemented in smartpy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is implemented in SmartPy. (I shared a few examples in previous threads)

Your solidity example:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 < 0.6.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

import "./RLPEncode.sol";

contract Sample {
    using RLPEncode for string;

    function encode(bytes memory _rlpBytes, string memory _link) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
        return abi.encodePacked(_rlpBytes, _link.encodeString());
    }
}
```

SmartPy code that produces the same encoding:

```
import smartpy as sp

Utils = sp.io.import_script_from_url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Acurast/acurast-hyperdrive/main/contracts/tezos/libs/utils.py")

class Sample(sp.Contract):

    @sp.onchain_view()
    def encode(self, arg):
        encode_string = sp.build_lambda(Utils.RLP.Encoder.encode_string)

        sp.result(arg.rlpBytes + encode_string(arg.link))

@sp.add_test("Tests")
def test():
    sc = sp.test_scenario()
    c = Sample()
    sc += c

    rlpBytes = sp.bytes("0x012345")
    result = sc.compute(c.encode(sp.record(rlpBytes = rlpBytes, link = "TEST")))
    sc.show(result)
    sc.verify(result == sp.bytes("0x0123458454455354"))
```

In both examples, if we use `rlpBytes = 0x012345` and `link = "TEST"`, we get `0x0123458454455354`.

Comment: so I have a question , i tried in solidity on the code i posted to encode the string "helloworld" and another string "hello" and the result is "0x8dcccb8a68656c6c6f776f726c64" and "0x88c7c68568656c6c6f" respectively. But in case of smartpy the prefix is 0x12345, can I do something to get the prefix of rlp bytes same as that of solidity ?

Comment: You do not show how `_rlpBytes` is being computed initially, in the example above I used `0x012345` just as an example.

Comment: it is just initialized, bytes memory _rlpBytes; .
where can I communicate with you directly, are you available on telegram or slack  ?

Comment: hey can you look at this question too, https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/6070/rlp-encoding-of-integer-in-negative-value