# RLP Encoding of integer in negative value

Tags: smartpy

I want to encode an integer i.e -10, but I don't see any function to encode the negative integer in this library.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Acurast/acurast-hyperdrive/main/contracts/tezos/libs/utils.py

How can I achieve this ?